When downloading files in getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(), they are not updated
In flutter, the db file is saved using the ftpConnect package and the path_provider package.
///download path
final Directory appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()..createSync(recursive: true);

File dbFile = File(appDocumentsDir/dbFileName);
bool donwloadres = await downloadDb(onProgress: (double newProgress){}); //true


//download ftp 
Future<bool> downloadDB({required Function(double) onProgress}) async {
    Directory appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()..createSync(recursive: true);
    bool bDbDownload = false;
    File dbFile = File("${appDocumentsDir.path}/$dbFileName");

    Database database = await openDatabase(
        "${appDocumentsDir.path}/$dbFileName");

    if(dbFile.existsSync()){
      dbFile.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }

    bDbDownload = await ftp.downloadFileWithRetry(
      dbFileName,
      dbFile,
      onProgress: (progress, received, total) {
        onProgress(progress);
      },
    );
    return bDbDownload;
  }


When the DB is updated and you re-download it again and run the app again, the previous DB is saved, not the latest downloaded DB. What are the reasons for this? There is no problem on iOS, but this problem only occurs on Android.
